# Renaming part of name of all files in a directory tree if match

Tags: bash, sed, files, find, rename

I have a directory tree like this

```
.
|-- players
|   |-- red_alice.plr
|   |-- red_bob.plr
|-- resources
|   |-- red_cash.rsc
|   |-- red_food.rsc
```

I want to go through all directories and rename any file that starts with "red" to instead start with "blue"...

I think it is work of find and sed commands but I am not sure how to formulate this situation...I know for example I can find files by

```
find . -name "red*" -type f
```

then how to use this output to rename red to blue?

Comment: Try `find path_to_dir/ -type f -name 'red_*' -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f/red/blue}"; done' _ {} +`  When satisfied, remove the `echo` part

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with rename command:

```
find . -type f -name "red*" -exec rename  s/red/blue/g "{}" +;
```

So it will find the files with name starting with `red` and then will put all of them in single command like

```
 rename s/red/blue/g red_first red_second
```

It will search for files in all directories below the current directory.

Comment: Cool. Didn't know `rename`. Also has a option `-n` to print what would be done instead of doing it.

Comment: Yeah, just verbose kind.

Comment: This did not change anything and also did not produce any error message..hmmm

Comment: It should work I tried it.

Comment: @P_Yadav I think the Linux machine I am working on is quite old and this way is not supported

Comment: @DEKKER Try to remove `+` and use `\;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
find . -name "red_*" -exec bash -c 'echo mv "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed "s%/red_%/blue_%" )"' \;
```

This just prints the commands. Good to check if it would actually work. If you verified that, remove the `echo` before `mv`.

Comment: hmm I get this error 'find missing argument to -exec''

Comment: Did you also add the `\;` at the end?